# Problems selecting date

Tags: sqlite

Here are some queries I'm making and the results I'm receiving. What I'm trying to end up with is a list of months and years. So I want to see a result of 02-2011, 03-2011, 04-2011. But I can't seem to get it... what should I do?

```
select date from record;
04-13-2011
04-14-2011
03-14-2011
02-14-2011
sqlite>

select strftime('%m-%Y') from record;
04-2011
04-2011
04-2011
04-2011
sqlite>

select date from record group by date('%m-%Y');
02-14-2011
sqlite>

select strftime('%m-%Y', date) from record group by date('%m-%Y');
note: blank row
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
select substr(date,0,5) from record;
```

Your date seems to be a string column. Anyway, in the second query you select *current* month and year for each row, the same goes for `GROUP BY` clause of subsequent queries.

Comment: select substr(date,0,3) as curmonth, substr(date,7,4) as curyear from record group by curyear, curmonth; -- it works! thanks